# Identifying fastener on 2013 VW Jetta TDI brake rotor

Tags: brakes, vw, tools, jetta

I'm trying to replace the rear brake pads and rotors on my 2013 VW Jetta TDI and I'm completely baffled by what type of screw this set screw or alignment screw is in the rotor face. It's 6-pointed so im guessing it's a Torx but I have tried T25 which is too small and T27 is too big. There isn't a T26. VW service departments tell me it's a T30 but there is no way. T27 is to big! Any help would keep me from blowing up this stupid car!

Picture of screw:

[image]

Comment: Allen wrenches can be used quite often in place of torx. It will fit right into the center of the Torx and will get the job done.

Comment: I did try a 4mm allen wrench which was the biggest that fit and it didn't grab enough. I would edit and add a picture if i could figure out how.

Comment: Do yo have anything that you could cut a slot in it (like a dremel) and used a flat blade screwdriver?

Comment: It looks like a torx but it actually isn't.  I would guess it's some bs snowflake of a special tool for VW's.  I'll try and tease it out.

Comment: You probably could have used the right size flat tip screwdriver as well. Jam it in and give it a crank.

Answer (score 3):

You use this fancy tool.

You push and turn the 'screw' at the same time to release the disc.

It's in German Brake loaner tool kits from most of the big automotive parts chains.

[image]

The tools kits for these brakes look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the input. It ended up being whats called a polydrive tip. Ridiculous how VW goes to such lengths to get you into a service department.